# How to install an Edimax EW-7833UAC in 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

I need instructions to install an [Edimax EW-7833UAC USB Wi-Fi adapter](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_ac1750_dual-band/ew-7833uac/) in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Well, easy to find with keyword = edimax ew-7833uac linux. ...  ... The first hit is https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000074625-how-to-install-ew-7833uac-in-linux-running-kernel-higher-than-v4-4

Comment: I have "Comfast 917AC 2.4G+5GHz Performance Dual Band AC 1750Mbps Wireless N WIFI USB Adapter - Chipset RTL8814AU" = works great with the drivers above.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
```

Open dkms.conf with your preferred text editor, e.g.

```
nano dkms.conf
```

Replace line 1 `MAKE="'make'"` with

```
MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
```

save the file and and exit your text editor, then

```
cd ..
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21
```

and reboot.