# Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I recently updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, but after updating, my TP Link T9UH Wi-Fi adapter doesn't work anymore.
It didn't work perfectly before (see [Install rtl8814AU driver on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014969/install-rtl8814au-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04)), but after removing and reinstalling the driver now and then, it would work again.

When I enter `sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21` it returns

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make'......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814au: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814au/4.3.21/build/make.log for more information.
```

How can I get my wifi adapter working again?

When I try the solution given here: [How to install an Edimax EW-7833UAC in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033825/how-to-install-an-edimax-ew-7833uac-in-18-04)
`sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21` returns:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This link might help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033825/how-to-install-an-edimax-ew-7833uac-in-18-04
I'm about to try it myself as I have a similar problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me. When I try that, my dkms status gives me:
`rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.15.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) `

Comment: It works! I deleted everything and reloaded the driver and after that it worked again. Very happy now!

Answer (score 6):

I personally use (and recommend) the drivers from aircrack-ng.
See [aircrack-ng/rtl8812au](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au) (@ *GitHub*).

<s>I recommend using the version **5.2.20** which introduces a very useful feature: A unique module (**88XX**) to "rules them all" (chipsets 8821AU, 8812au and 8814au).</s>
**Edit**: The master (default) branch is now **v5.6.4.2** and it is the best option (unique module for all chipsets from RealTek 88XX.au family).

In order to install the drivers, you need first to install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install bc
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install git
```

Then download the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
```

Locate your shell in the downloaded repository

```
cd rtl8812au
```

<s>Switch to the branch 5.2.20</s>

*Edit: No need to switch branch now, default branch is the best option*

Finally, compile and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Notice that an even more recent version: Branch 5.3.4,
But I had some problems to get it works with 8814au. Hopefully it will be fixed in the future (if it is not already done).

Comment: Linux Mint 19.2 (cinnamon),  kernel 4.15.0-58, USB Wi-fi TP-Link Archer T9UH(EU) ver. 2 - works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this approach, but I'm getting terrible connection speed. I've tried to install various versions using DKMS. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: i can't do magic, you need to be much more specific... The post is from some time ago, the only advice i can give you is to **not** switch branch as the default branch is now the latest one and much more actual then the 5.2.20

Comment: You're an everyday hero.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the following to get my USB WiFi-AC working - not sure if you require 8814 though.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

It worked OK using both netplan settings and through the GUI

Comment: Any update about 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

For this driver, here is what works for me every time on Ubuntu desktop 18.04 thru 20.04:

Make sure USB wireless device not inserted

1. Update the system:
   `$ sudo apt update`
2. Install required packages:
   `$ sudo apt install git && build-essential`
3. Download the driver:
   `$ sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au`
4. Go to the directory:
   `$ cd rtl8812au`
5. Do the next commands consecutively:
   `$ sudo make clean`
   `$ sudo make`
   `$ sudo make uninstall`
   `$ sudo make install`

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

-Persists reboots