# How to get RTL8814AU as Alfa AWUSB1900 working in Kubuntu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, kubuntu

[Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042310/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-18-04)
I tried that question, it appears as if the tip for getting it to work in Kali Linux :
    sudo apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms

Yields no access to a suitable driver for the device. I've also tried various git clone repos but no go. As of now it will lock up my shut down if I plug the wireless adapter in. If I try to use any of the git clone repos it gets stuck at the depmod/modprobe and the machine also cannot shut down (it hangs the system eternally). What can I do to get this working in Kubuntu? I don't want to switch to Kali Linux because it might not support my touch screen...
Also my dpkg --configure -a is required now, and it can't fix my system. I cannot run updates anymore.. It goes to 'depmod' then hangs eternally even stopping the system from shutting down.

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5659 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8813 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8814AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$
```

Here's an example of the 'depmod' or 'modprobe' system hang:

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up rtl8812au-dkms (4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu12) ...
Removing old rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  rtl8812au
Version: 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg
Kernel:  5.3.0-29-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------
Status: This module version was INACTIVE for this kernel.
depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-29-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-29-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

8812au.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Good news! Module version v4.3.8_12175.20140902 for 8812au.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.3.0-29-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...
```

lspci:

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$
```

Nothing conclusive in dmesg:

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ dmesg|tail -20
[  336.849180] mce: CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849181] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849183] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849184] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849226] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849227] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849228] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849230] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849231] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.849232] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[  336.850380] mce: CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[  336.850381] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850382] mce: CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[  336.850383] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850385] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850386] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850387] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850390] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850420] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[  336.850421] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$
```

I am stuck, even Kali Linux's instructions don't work:

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ sudo apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$
```

Per suggestion below:
now my 'updates' doesn't get past 'Installing'...
my system is broken.
I will reinstall Kubuntu later. but I think I'm going to have to return the card.

modprobe rtl8812au didn't work with the card plugged in or not.

It now works as it appears :

```
charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ sudo ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1101  bytes 130024 (130.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1101  bytes 130024 (130.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.43.38.49  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.43.255.255
        ether 18:1d:ea:20:15:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1722  bytes 700612 (700.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2152  bytes 304505 (304.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx00c0caaa328a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 2312
        ether 00:c0:ca:aa:32:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 61  bytes 18183 (18.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105  bytes 15430 (15.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

charles@charles-Inspiron-5482:~/Documents$ sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

But I've no idea how to make it the OS's default card.

Comment: First, fix the "`you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. `.

Comment: I fixed it with sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-<forgot what i used but it worked>
Now getting this:
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms

Comment: Don't add info in comments. Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1211381/edit ) Your post to add info. I've had success with the `git` branch: `git clone `https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git`

Comment: it installed correctly and didn't hang at modprobe, but i get kernel module crash in dmesg when I plug the device in, where do I go from here? I think it is still taking off the old one 8812au.ko there is some tainted module there...

Comment: Remove all dkms drivers that you've installed. Then check the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10. Pay no attention to the filename that says 8812.