# Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, upgrade, usb, kernel

Based on this

[Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042310/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I installed manually (make && make install) the driver when I had the kernel

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-26-generic
```

Now, ubuntu 20.04 wants to install the new one:

linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic

I did it before (upgrade the system then, the kernel) and the driver stopped to work, even I installed thousand times, was impossible to up the driver which logical name is "wlx50c4ddcf488e".

The installation I made:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
$ sudo apt install bc
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
$ sudo apt install git

$ git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

$ cd rtl8812au
$ make && sudo make install
```

Does anyone has idea about what can I do? Now, I cannot upgrade my system without losing the wireless connection.

Thank a lot.

Comment: OP installed wothout using dkms.

Comment: Uninstall your current manually built driver, and then see the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10 which builds the same driver using dkms. First install dkms if you don't already have it installed.

Answer (score 5):

I followed this at github on my Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked perfectly.
https://github.com/morrownr/8814au

> 8814au ( 8814au.ko )
> Linux Driver for USB WiFi Adapters that are based on the RTL8814AU Chipset

#### Installation

Need to install some packages:

```
sudo apt install dkms git
```

Now make a directory to build the driver and enter it:

```
mkdir src
cd src
```

Download the driver and then enter the 8814au directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8814au.git
cd 8814au
```

Run the installation script

```
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

And reboot.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 21.04 - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're building drivers for the current running kernel. Use DKMS if you want to rebuild the drivers for every new release. `make dkms_install` should do the job for you.