# How do I install a .tar file that it has no configure to drive the LAN card?

Tags: wireless, hard-drive, lan

I am trying to drive a new LAN card `A5000UA`, I downloaded its file's drive from this [link](http://iptime.com/iptime/?page_id=126&dffid=12&dfsid=6&uid=23755&mod=document).

I used to extract the .tar using this command:

```
tar xvf rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.7.6.1_36803.20200508.tar
```

I would like to do:

```
./configure
```

Sadly, I didn't find `./configure`.
As you see in the figure:

[image: folder content]

I found the drive commands for  `A3000UA`  [here](https://kyubot.tistory.com/133).

It is working well for `A3000UA`.
What do I do in this case?

Comment: try direct with `make && (sudo) make install`

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you need to compile it? It is [already packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=8188%20ko).

Comment: @lucki1000, Thanks for your help. I tried to use it. The output is:  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `make'

Comment: @N0rbert,  Thanks for your help. My  Ubuntu version is old (16.04)

Comment: It is working well now, I followed this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239986/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-20-04/1324954#1324954,  and the same here https://hamonikr.org/board_Device/100148

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239986/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @karel, No, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Please don't confuse us with questions about end of life versions. Old versions behave differently from current versions and everyone here will assume a current version. 16.04 is off topic here :) I would advice to upgrade if you want help from AU

Comment: @Rinzwind, Thanks for your advice, sure, I will upgrade it. I am waiting to finish our current project.