# After kernel upgrade to 5.19.0-32 generic for Lubuntu 22.04, TPLink Archer T9UH v1.0 failed

Tags: wireless, kernel, 22.04

Lubuntu did an auto update. After reboot, the wifi is not working and TPLink Archer T9UH v1.0 is not been detected. I tried to remove rtl8814au/5.8.5.1 and reinstall but the error messages are as per below:

```
'make' -j6 KVER=5.19.0.32-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/5.19.0.32-generic/build....(bad exit status:2)
ERROR(dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814au:5.8.5.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.19.0-32 generic

An error occurred. dims build error =10.
```

Please advice how ti fix this issue.

Comment: I able install a new driver from https://github.com/morrownr/8814au#readme. It resolved the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239986/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Just FYI:   If your system is *stable* using the GA kernel (5.15), it's supported for the life of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*default on Server systems & some ISOs*) and have your system not upgrade to later HWE kernel stack choices.  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for clues esp. "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*" section...   You can also have both GA & HWE installed, though some closed-source kernel modules (nvidia etc) may prevent both stacks from co-existing; but they can co-exist if using all open-source code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `lsusb` command.