# Dongle wifi TP-LINK AC600 Archer T2U (8811au) not working in ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, usb, network-manager, realtek-wireless, 21.04

I have this issue https://github.com/morrownr/8812au/issues/27#issuecomment-846984591

I tried Morrownr/8812au and Morrownr/8821au and aircrack-ng/rtl8812au. But I not have wireless in my ubuntu desktop yet.

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2357:011e TP-Link AC600 wireless Realtek RTL8811AU [Archer T2U Nano]
```

**mokutil --sb-state**

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
wlxd03745db188a  unassociated  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL8821AU"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**dkms status**

```
rtl8821au, 5.8.2.3, 5.11.0-17-generic, x86_64: installe
```

**lsmod**

```
8821au               1957888  0
cfg80211              892928  2 8821au,88XXau
```

**sudo ip link set wlan0 up**

```
Cannot find device "wlan0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install bc
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install git

git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git

cd rtl8812au

make
sudo make install
```

**Retrieved from:** [Install driver rtl8814au on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042310/install-driver-rtl8814au-on-ubuntu-18-04)